# Hide error message in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have problem to hide error message from shell command as the following case.

```
firs_line=$(head -n 1 file) > /dev/null 2>&1
```

I expect that the error message will be hidden but actually it doesn't.
How to get output while `head` command is executed successfully but hide error message when it fails?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: put the error redirection inside the `$()`. as is its trying to redirect the assignment, not the command output

Comment: What error are you expecting that you know you can ignore the error? Presumably, you are OK with `firs_line` having an empty value when the call to `head` fails.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Is the error message coming from the `head` program (like, file not found)?

In this case you have to redirect the output from inside parens:

```
firs_line=$(head -n 1 file 2>/dev/null)
```

Moreover, you only have to redirect standard error (and not standard output which is supposed to be catched by `$()` to be stored in `firs_line`

Answer (score 2):

```
firs_line="$([ -r file ] && head -n 1 file)"
```

Comment: +1. It makes sense to prevent errors instead of silencing them, and the error he talks about is most likely related to files missing or not readable (any other thing would be weird and probably better if printed out). But you should explain the rationale behind your code in a couple lines for future reference